# Object of Object to Array of Objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
  let data = {
    code:{
      name:{firstname:'Demo', lastname:'demo2'}
    }
  };
```

How to convert above code to below format

```
let data1 = [
{dataFirstname:'Demo',dataLastName:'demo2'}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? is data an Array or just an object with one property `code`?

Comment: Data is an Object

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
let data = {
    code:{
      name:{firstname:'Demo', lastname:'demo2'}
    }
 };

const result = Object.keys(data).map(item => {
    return data[item];
});

console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept this as an answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let data1 = [{ 
  dataFirstname: data.code.name.firstname, 
  dataLastName: data.code.name.lastname
}];
```

```js
let data = {
    code:{
      name:{firstname:'Demo', lastname:'demo2'}
    }
  };

let data1 = [{ 
  dataFirstname: data.code.name.firstname, 
  dataLastName: data.code.name.lastname
}];

console.log(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  let data = {
        code:{
          name:{firstname:'Demo', lastname:'demo2'}
        }
      };
    
    let data1=[]
    
    Object.keys(data).forEach(element => {
          let obj={dataFirstname:data[element].name.firstname,
          dataLastName:data[element].name.lastname}; 
          data1.push(obj)
        });
        
        console.log(data1)
        //outPut [ {  "dataFirstname": "Demo", "dataLastName": "demo2"  }]
```